# Weight is always zero

Tags: magento2, shipping

I am using Owebia Shipping extension for Magento 2. I entered a rule in that shipping method which says if the weight is `> 0` the shipping will be $5.

This always gave me the "No shipping method available" message in the checkout. So I changed the rule to `>= 0` and the $5 were shown.

I checked my products and they all have a weight > 0 in kilogram. **I also tried other shipping methods / extensions, it all comes down to the same problem - weight is always 0 in my shop even though the products have a weight assigned.**

Any idea what might be the problem here?

**Magento 2.2.5**

Answer (score 0):

We are using Owebia shipping extension with 2.2.6 without issues, please see some weight based rules below:

```
if ($request->package_weight < 0.9){
    addMethod('id_001', [
    'title' => "UK postal delivery up to 900g",
    'price'      => 5.95,
    ]);
}
else if ($request->package_weight < 1.9){
    addMethod('id_002', [
    'title' => "UK postal delivery up to 2kg",
    'price'      => 7.95,
    ]);
}
if ($request->package_weight < 1.75){
    addMethod('id_003', [
    'title' => "UK weekday special delivery up to 1.75kg",
    'price'      => 12.95,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is not the extension, the problem is that the weight is always zero in my shop, even though, the products have a weight.

Comment: Is the combobox next to the weight in the product details set to "This item has weight"?

Comment: Yes, it is set correctly on all levels.